# Programatically Click a Iron Router Link in MeteorJS

Tags: meteor, iron-router

When you click on an iron router link, MeteorJS will change the template that is being renderd into the page. this is not a traditional page reload.

how can i achieve this programically?

for example: i have a hyperlink defined by `"{{pathFor 'settings'}}"`, clicking on it will change the template being displayed to the 'settings' template. but when i do this programatically with `"window.location='http://localhost/settings'"`, a page refresh is triggered and any variables i may have initialised are gone.

i think i can achieve the result i want by adding a 'trigger click' event in jquery, but i was wondering if there is a better/simpler solution available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `Router.go('settings');`. You can either provide a path or a route name if you set one.